# Akka.NET Configuration settings for remoting

Tags: c#, .net, akka, akka-remote-actor, akka-remoting

I am using the example on the [Akka.NET github](https://github.com/akkadotnet/akka.net) to play with some basic remoting.

In the remoting example available from GitHub there is the following section in the configuration string for Akka.NET.

```
deployment {
    /localactor {
        router = round-robin-pool
        nr-of-instances = 5
    }
    /remoteactor {
        router = round-robin-pool
        nr-of-instances = 5
        remote = ""akka.tcp://system2@localhost:666""
    }
}
remote {
   dot-netty.tcp {
   port = 1234
   hostname = localhost
}
```

1. What does the forward slash / indicate? is this a comment or is this just the format of the files?
2. What does the router option 'round-robin-pool' control? I can see that it maps to the [following class](https://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/current/akka/routing/RoundRobinPool.html) but I am hoping someone can explain what akka.routing actually means in the context of a remoting scenario? I am assuming this has something to do with how urls or ips are mapped?

Any clarification would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following snippet from the example:

```
/localactor {
    router = round-robin-pool
    nr-of-instances = 5
}
```

> What does the forward slash / indicate? is this a comment or is this just the format of the files?

The forward slash is not a comment; it indicates the name of an actor. The [code](https://github.com/akkadotnet/akka.net/blob/v1.3.2/src/examples/RemoteDeploy/System1/Program.cs#L68) in the example refers to the actor named `localactor` in the following way:

```
var local = system.ActorOf(Props.Create(() => new SomeActor("hello", 123)).WithRouter(FromConfig.Instance), "localactor");
```

> What does the router option 'round-robin-pool' control? I can see that it maps to the following class but I am hoping someone can explain what akka.routing actually means in the context of a remoting scenario? I am assuming this has something to do with how urls or ips are mapped?

`round-robin-pool` is used to define a [router](https://getakka.net/articles/actors/routers.html). `localactor` in the above configuration snippet is a router actor that creates a [pool](https://getakka.net/articles/actors/routers.html#pools-vs-groups) of five routee instances to which it routes messages in [round-robin](https://getakka.net/articles/actors/routers.html#roundrobin) order. A router has no special meaning in a remoting context; it is essentially no different from a router in a non-remoting scenario. You can read more about routers in the linked documentation.